# Can't start Laravel web socket in Docker

Tags: laravel, docker, websocket

This is my first time working with docker. I have a laravel websocket site (php + laravel + postgresql) that needs to be put into a container.
If I just execute commands (no docker):

**php artisan serve**

**php artisan websockets: serve**

then it works successfully:

- Websockets dashboard http://127.0.0.1:8000/laravel-websockets
- Can send POST message to http://127.0.0.1:8000/telephonyCall for websocket server.
- The client listens to the socket server on port 6001 and successfully accepts the sent messages.

I did a docker installation following the instruction https://www.twilio.com/blog/get-started-docker-laravel with minor changes (added 6001 port to docker-compose.yml).

Now I have available in the container:

- Apache default page http://192.168.1.61/
- laravel's default page http://192.168.1.61:8080/
- If I run **php artisan websockets: serve**, I see in the console that the socket server responds to client connections on port 6001, but does not respond to sending messages.

Unavailable:

- websockets dashboard http://192.168.1.61:8080/laravel-websockets
- Sending POST messages http://192.168.1.61:8080/telephonyCall for websocket server

Please tell me what I did wrong?

**Directory structure:**

```
docker 
 apache
   ¬ default.conf
 databases
 php
   ¬ Dockerfile
 src
   ¬ (here is a copy of the working site)
 ¬ docker-compose.yml
```

**default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName WebSocketServer
   DocumentRoot /var/www/WebSocketServer/public
   <Directory /var/www/WebSocketServer>
       AllowOverride All
   </Directory>
   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:8.0-apache

RUN apt update && apt install -y zlib1g-dev g++ libicu-dev zip libzip-dev zip libpq-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install intl opcache pdo pgsql pdo_pgsql \
    && pecl install apcu \
    && docker-php-ext-enable apcu \
    && docker-php-ext-configure zip \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip

WORKDIR /var/www/WebSocketServer

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'

services:
    database:
        image: postgres
        container_name: database
        restart: unless-stopped
        environment:
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 1111111
            POSTGRES_DB: websocket
        volumes:
            - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        ports:
            - '5432:5432'

    php-apache:
        container_name: php-apache
        build:
            context: ./php
        ports:
            - '8080:80'
            - '8000:8000'
            - '6001:6001'
        volumes:
            - ./src:/var/www/WebSocketServer
            - ./apache/default.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
        depends_on:
            - database
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run the command

```
php artisan serve
```

then it starts on the localhost. If

```
php artisan serve --host = 192.168.1.61
```

it will be accessible from the outside (here 192.168.1.61 is the ip address of the machine on which we are running). But the container uses its own network and 192.168.1.61 for it is "outside the network", so the artisan cannot start.

To make the page http://192.168.1.61:8080/laravel-websockets available, you need to run like this:

```
php artisan serve --host = 0.0.0.0
```